# What replaces the deprecated features in CouchDB 3.0?

Tags: database, couchdb

It like looks several CouchDB features are deprecated in 3.0 and will be removed in 4.0. Is this functionality gone or just moved somewhere else?

Removed functionality (per: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/whatsnew/3.0.html#deprecated-feature-warnings)

```
Show functions (/{db}/{ddoc}/_show)
List functions (/{db}/{ddoc}/_list)
Update functions (/{db}/{ddoc}/_update)
Virtual hosts and ini-file rewrites
Rewrite functions (/{db}/{ddoc}/_rewrite)
```

How are rewrites handled in 4.0?

Comment: I think this question is too broad. How to replace the functionality of each of these features should be a separate question, as the answers will be unrelated to each other.

Comment: @Flimzy These seem like major functionality, so I was hoping there would be documentation about what was replacing them or a migration guide. Happy to have an answer with several links.

Comment: You may be happy to have an answer with several links, but that would be off-topic for SO. Each question should have exactly one "correct" answer.

Comment: The one correct answer might be a list of links

Comment: Yes, but, now for the third time, such a correct answer is _off topic_ on StackOverflow.

Comment: It's not _your_ web site. The rules that questions should be focused are long-established.

Comment: @danwoods it may be helpful to understand *why* these features are deprecated.  See [this](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/2218#issuecomment-593500410) and [that](https://blog.couchdb.org/2020/02/26/the-road-to-couchdb-3-0-prepare-for-4-0/).  Those that steer CouchDB decided to move away from "CouchApps" and have CouchDB be "just" a DB, not a DB *and* Application Server.  Your question(s) invite speculation; e.g. `_show` could be implemented in middleware or client side.  Any sober answer depends on a use-case, and lacking a use-case, any answer would be opinionated guess work.

Comment: @RamblinRose If you post an answer that says, "Those that steer CouchDB decided to move away from "CouchApps" and have CouchDB be "just" a DB, not a DB and Application Server.", with those links, I'll accept that as the answer.

Love the username, btw.

Comment: @RamblinRose Or really just an answer that says "nothing" 

Comment: @danwoods Hey now! Thanks a lot and I am happy to have helped.  Since there is a question as to whether or not the question is legit for SO, I'll pass - I'm good on points! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not being replaced. CouchDB will no longer support CouchApps going forward.

See:

- https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/2218#issuecomment-593500410
- https://blog.couchdb.org/2020/02/26/the-road-to-couchdb-3-0-prepare-for-4-0/

Comment: Does it mean couchdb is dead? what could we use as a replacement?